# Cannot get 'isFunction' helper to work with typescript

Tags: typescript

I made a simple helper to check if value is a function

```
export function isFunction<T>(value: T) {
  return value instanceof Function;
}
```

I then use it in scenario like this

```
if (isFunction(callback)) {
  callback(arguments);
}
```

But I get typescript error for this line `callback(arguments);` saying

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

This is probably due to `callback` type being `callback?: (value: number) => void`, however I thought that typescript would be smart enough to check what that `isFunction` helper returns? Is there a way to make this work somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
function isFunction(value: any): value is Function {
  return value instanceof Function;
}
```

Basically if this evaluates to `true`, it means that `value` is not `undefined` and that it's instance of `Function`.

Please see [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgMXNeYAUA3AQwBsQBTALkQLAE8BKSwk05FRDSWBRAbwChEiAE6koIIUiZlkYFFGoRScYO0xcwAbj4BfPnyg0ADiwCyNACpGWAXl4DEEYkQBGBCAGsA-JXzEylMBAAW2dSITpEawA+RDw4GAATHT0iUUQwOCgAEVJgGDBSBMozS2NI3m0tPhgVHFQOLAQcDOzc-MKAOkciFzd3Ogj+QQgEFDhUjqI4AHMcAHIWhydCubotQRacvIKErqdXDxwAJjXkvlSoRAS2neKLK3KhpZ6D9x8pCnTg0PDImKfBPZdJU9DVEHV0GpsDhrttOt1eh4BnZhqNxqRJjN5giVqdBLD2rsEa9jqddHwgA).